# Organizing "Sent" mail

Tags: mail.app, email

Operating system: *macOS Monterey version 12.0.1*.

In *Apple Mail*, I use *Smart Mailboxes* to organize incoming mail.
I'd like to better organize *Sent mail*.
Does any means exist within Apple Mail to organize *Sent mail* by directing sent mail into specific folders?

If possible, how do I do it?

Alternatively, does mail have any other capacity (such as *Numbers* ability or organize data by *category*) to address the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a clunky way to do this.

In `Mail`, under `On My Mac`, I set up a folder called "Sent ordered"

Under this folder I set up a number of sub folders.

In `Mail > Preferences > Rules` I set up a number of rules.  Each rule has a configuration like the following:

[image]

Again, a bit clunky but it works.

Comment: You can do similar with smart mailboxes - set the From setup and thgen the other rulkes